# error request-default-error-callback generated by Activity watch mode

Tags: call-process

I have this error since installing the activity watch mode package.

Any idea on how correct it ?
The only setup I did was

```lisp
(global-activity-watch-mode)
```

I've tried

```lisp
 (setq global-activity-watch-mode nil)
```

Didn't make this error go away...

Comment: not sure I used the right tag for the question. Couldn't find procrastination ;)

Comment: Where did you put the setup line? If you added it to your init file, get rid of it and restart emacs. If you just evaluated it without adding it to your init file, all you have to do is restart emacs.

Comment: @NickD OK, so I was missing the reboot step. Thanks. Still, somewhat surprised the nil value did not do the job. I suppose it's due to the global nature of this variable. I am correct ?